# How to customize the apps in the Windows 8 search bar?

Tags: windows-8, search

When I start searching from the Start screen, a list of apps appears under the search bar. Clicking on any of those gives results from that specific app.

Is there any way to remove/add apps to that list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is a way just press the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> from desktop and select the `Change PC settings` now under the `search` an option is **Use these apps to search** is available just turn off the app you don't want to appear there.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can add *any* app to that list. Apps that have been developed to use the **Search Contract** are automatically added to that list.

Please see the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465238.aspx

> Let users search your Windows Store app by adding the Search contract. When you add the Search contract, users can search your app from anywhere in their system by selecting the Search charm.

And this link has the details

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465233.aspx

**To hide an app from the list,**

1. Right click on the app
2. Click on Hide

[image]

Comment: And is there any way to remove any of the apps?

Comment: Yes apps can be hidden from the list. Please see the edited answer.